# How can SSL traffic be intercepted by a fake certificate

Tags: http, ssl, networking

I would like to know if I run web debugging software like charles, how its possible to use a fake certificate without the server knowing?

I just want to understand the workflow.

If I get a custom generated cert with public key, how can the server allow a session between client and server if the fake public key does not conform to the private key of the server?

For me it does not make sense. How can I send data using a fake ssl cert and the server does not reject my request? How this is possible?

I have googled a lot but did not find any answers to my question

Comment: Your question is not clear, and you should specify what "charles" is. Are you faking up a client certificate or a server certificate? A lot of vulnerabilities happen because applications do not check properly (or at all) the certificate of the other party. See https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html for examples.

Comment: This question is more on-topic at [security.se]. And it also has an answer there which explains how SSL interception works: [How does SSL Proxy server in company work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133254/how-does-ssl-proxy-server-in-company-work). *"How can I send data using a fake ssl cert and the server does not reject my request?"* - this part shows a wrong understanding of TLS: the client is not sending a fake cert, in fact apart from mutual authentication the client never sends a certificate but only the server does.